# How to create Python module distribution to gracefully fall-back to pure Python code

Tags: python, software-distribution

I have written a Python module, and I have two versions: a pure Python implementation and a C extension. I've written the `__init__.py` file so that it tries to import the C extension, and if that fails, it imports the pure Python code (is that reasonable?).

Now, I'd like to know what is the best way to distribute this module (e.g. write `setup.py`) so it can be easily used by people with or without the facility to build, or use, the C extension, just by running:

```
python setup.py install
```

My experience is limited, but I see two possible cases:

- User does not have MS Visual Studio, or the GCC compiler suite, installed on their machine, to build the C extension
- User is running IronPython, Jython, or anything other than CPython. I only have used CPython. So I'm not sure how I could distribute this module so that it would work smoothly and be easy to install on those platforms, if they're unable to use the C extension.

Comment: I've raised an issue about this for http://guide.python-distribute.org/ -- see http://bitbucket.org/tarek/hitchhiker-guide-packaging/issue/14/how-to-create-a-module-distribution-to-gracefully-fall-back-to-pure-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> (is that reasonable?).

Yep, perfectly sensible.

To catch the "no suitable C compiler case": the call to `setup(...)` will do a sys.exit in case of problems.  So, first try it with the `ext_modules` argument set as desired, within a `try`:

```
try:
  setup(..., ext_modules=...)
except SystemExit: ...
```

and in the `except` clause, call `setup(...)` again *without* the `ext_modules` (so it gives up on building and installing the extensions).  The user who's installing will still see messages like "unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory", but you can appropriately add your own messages to inform the user that it's no big deal and that you're trying again without the extension modules.

To support non-CPython implementations, in your `setup.py` you can test `sys.version` (I'm not sure what the value will be for each non-CPython implementation, but IronPython has an `'IronPython'` substring there, for example), to avoid even trying the `ext_modules` part. If you miss some such implementation in your checks, the try/except should probably catch most others anyway, just with a modest amount of wasted work;-).

Answer (score 0):

"tries to import the C extension, and if that fails, it imports the pure Python code (is that reasonable?)."

Almost.  Read about `cStringIO` and `StringIO`.  Also read about `cPickle` and `Pickle`.  Also read about `cElementTree` and `ElementTree`.

If the C version can't be built, that's one use case.  The pure Python version is the only one available.

If the C version can be built, however, I still have good reasons for declining it.  Primary, I would consider declining the C version because it may not allow the depth of subclass that I require for my application.

I don't want to be forced to use the C version, just because I happened to have the correct compiler.  I prefer to make those decisions on my own.

Consequently, I don't like the idea of some part of your module making my architecture decisions for me.  I prefer to choose which to import.  If the C version doesn't exist, that doesn't change my decision process, because I may still be creating subclasses of the pure Python version.

Bottom line.  Automate less.  Provide the two modules.  I prefer to choose which one to import.

Comment: In Python 3, the decision was made to go the other way, if I understand: there's just a `pickle` module, no `cPickle`. Quoting the Python 3.1 docs for `pickle`: "The `pickle` module has an transparent optimizer (`_pickle`) written in C. It is used whenever available. Otherwise the pure Python implementation is used."

Comment: Is it not possible to sub-class a Python class defined by a C extension? Incidentally, in the module I'm writing, there are no classes, just a few functions. But I'm still curious.

Comment: @Craig McQueen: Yes, there are examples of what you're doing. So what?  There are also examples that take the opposite approach.   That's my point.  Creating a  C-language class which can be subclassed is rarely done; I don't know how hard it is; I assume very hard.  A module that's all functions with no class definition is probably designed incorrectly, but perhaps is designed properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for Planar](http://pygamesf.org/~casey/planar/doc/overview.html), you can make the `setup.py` file for building the C extensions as normal, and then:

> To build and install Planar from the source distribution or repository use:

```
python setup.py install
```

> To install only the pure-Python modules without compiling, use:

```
python setup.py build_py install --skip-build
```